# How do I remove data in a csv file using Terminal in OSX

Tags: csv

I need to remove all emails from various ISP's within a csv file.
How do I proceed as they are scattered throughout the file?

Answer (score 0):

Hey if you know the emails that you want to remove you could do it like this:

```
 sed 's/email@mail1.com\|email@mail2.com\|email@mail3.com//g' yourfile.csv > newfile.csv
```

yes we can!

```
sed '/@mail.com/d' yourfile.csv > newfile.csv
```

Comment: Unfortunately, there are several names @mail.com

Comment: can we find all '@mail.com' and delete entire row?